# Difficulties with using external style sheet

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS and seem to have difficulties using an external style sheet.
This is the code on my style sheet named "page_style.css":

```
p{
    color:#383838
    font-family:tahoma
    }

h1
    {
    color: #00A300
    font-family:david
    }

h2
    {
    color:pink
    text-align:center
    font-family:arial
    }
```

And this is the code on my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="F:\Projects\Programming\CSS\In CSS\Try and Fun\Level 1\page_style.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a big text</h1>
<h2>This is a smaller text</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried writing "page_style.css" in the href instead of the whole link but it didn't help either. Tried changing the direction of the "slash" ('/' vs '\') and didn't work either.

Comment: href should be relative to html. Like if you have html and css in same directory, then href will only be file name.css

Comment: I have tried that but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is missing semicolons in the css:

```
p{
    color:#383838;
    font-family:tahoma;
}

h1{
    color: #00A300;
    font-family:david;
}

h2{
    color:pink;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

Browsers don't read the full file path unless you use the `file:///` protocol: `file:///F:\Projects\Programming\CSS\In CSS\Try and Fun\Level 1\page_style.css`. But some browsers will not cross to the file protocol from the http protocol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a big text</h1>
<h2>This is a smaller text</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I have written, I have tried it already but unfortunately i't didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! THat was the problem (the semicolons in the CSS), along with the href in the HTML (which I tried before).